# Strange Queue<T>.Enqueue(T item) code

Tags: c#, .net

While reflecting with ILSpy i found this line of code in the `Queue<T>.Enqueue(T item)`-method:

```
if (this._size == this._array.Length)
{
    int num = (int)((long)this._array.Length * 200L / 100L);
    if (num < this._array.Length + 4)
    {
        num = this._array.Length + 4;
    }
    this.SetCapacity(num);
}
```

I'm just wondering why somebody would do this? I think it's some kind of a integer overflow check, but why multiply first with `200L` and then divide by `100L`?

Might this have been a issue with earlier compilers?

Comment: @UrbanEsc It's used for array resizing

Comment: It can't be related to overflow, since `(long)_array.Length * 200` will never overflow. The `+ 4` stuff is to ensure that the array still grows even if its original size is zero.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis But it's const, so the compiler could optimize it. As i said in the question i think this might be a issue with earlier compilers.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I didn't mean the `* 200L`, i mean the conversion into long and than back to int.

Comment: @FelixK.: There's probably no checking going on here. The cast to long merely ensures that `...*200/100` doesn't overflow, and the cast to int is there simply because `num` is defined as `int`.

Comment: @FelixK. If I copy paste that code into VS2008, it does not optimize the *200/100 into *2.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I tested it right now, and you are correct. seems that the compiler isn't optimizing it. Maybe you could add this to your answer.

Comment: @FelixK. I kept messing up where to type :) added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually things first multiplied then divided by 100 are percentage calculations - Perhaps there was some `const XxxPercentage = 200` or something like that in the original code. The compiler does not seem to optimize the `* 200 / 100` to `* 2`.

This code sets the capacity to twice its size - but if twice its size would be smaller than the original size + 4, use that instead.

The reason it is converted to long probably is because if you multiply an integer by the "200 percent" it would overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Below are all the same and will generate the same result:

```
int size = (int)((length * 200L) / 100L);
int size = length << 1;
int size = length * 2;
```

The reason for choosing the first option over the other is to show your intend clearly:

```
const long TotalArraySize = 200L;
const long BytesPerElement = 100L;
return (length * TotalArraySize) / BytesPerElement;
```

Some details about performance implications are given here: [Doubling a number - shift left vs. multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059719/doubling-a-number-shift-left-vs-multiplication)

Comment: Are you sure that promoting `length` to `long`, then performing a long multiply followed by a long divide actually qualifies as a performance optimization?

Comment: @TeomanSoygul Your answer is not wrong, but it's still the question why the compiler doesn't optimize `200L / 100L`.

Answer (score 4):

If you continue looking to Queue implementation, you will find following fields:

```
const int _GrowFactor = 200;
const int _MinimumGrow = 4;
```

Interesting point is that those constants not used :) I think those constants were hardcoded instead (grow factor also replaced by long type). Lets look for Enqueue method from this point of view:

```
if (this._size == this._array.Length)
{
    int capacity = (int)((this._array.Length * _GrowFactor) / 100L);
    if (capacity < (this._array.Length + _MinimumGrow))
    {
        capacity = this._array.Length + _MinimumGrow;
    }
    this.SetCapacity(capacity);
}
```

I think those names make sense. GrowFactor specifies in percents how much array should grow. This is 200% by default. But they also specified minimum grow for internal array. So, if array didn't grow so much as current length + minimum grow, we give this minimal grow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Intent of `* 200L / 100L` is not any more clearer than `* 2` in my opinion. The only reason I can think of why it is done like that is to make sure queue length can grow up to 200 times. There is difference in `* 200 / 100` and `* 2` such that the first one will result in an overflow exception for 100 times smaller number. For example if it was for byte values, `x * 200 / 100` would fail for x==2 but `* 2` would fail only if x was as big as 128.

But as Marcelo Cantos pointed out `(long)this._array.Length * 200L / 100L` will never overflow so my answer is probably not helping much.

Can it be a 'feature' of ILSpy? Maybe in source code it is just `* 2`.

**EDIT**

After additional investigation it looks that this strange code must be an artefact of some refactoring. I have checked how it's done in List<>

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
    if (this._items.Length < min)
    {
        int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
        if (num < min)
        {
            num = min;
        }
        this.Capacity = num;
    }
}
```

It is as straightforward as you would expect. My guess is that `Queue.Enqueue` code was reworked but not fully cleaned up and some strange code resulted out of this change. Most developers assume that Microsoft libraries are perfect and everything has a meaning but it is quite likely that not every line of code is written by a genius :-)